# Laravel: temporary cache file for frequently updated mysql result?

Tags: php, mysql, caching, laravel-4

I have a case where I need to pull data with mysql like this:

```
 <tbody align="center">
 <?php 
     $faculty = Faculty::where('user_id', $user_instance->id)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(10);
 ?>
 @foreach ($faculty as $f)
 <?php
    if ($f->branch === null) $b_count = 'All';
    else {
        $b_count = explode(',', $f->branch);
        $b_count = count($b_count);
    }
    if ($f->programs === null) $p_count = 0;
    else {
        $p_count = explode(',', $f->programs);
        $p_count = count($p_count);
    }
    if ($f->sub_programs === null) $sp_count = 0;
    else {
        $sp = json_decode($f->sub_programs, true);
        $sp_count = 0;
        foreach ($sp as $s) {
            foreach ($s as $c) {
            $sp_count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
  ?>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
</tbody>
```

As the data grows, this query becomes slow. I have heard that it is possible to cache query of mysql data, but caching is only good for mostly static data, and the data from the code pulled daily.

I have used Laravel for the development, but any non-Laravel solution is also welcome.

Comment: I see you're paginating the query, so no matter how big the table you always get *N* results...Or am I missing something?

Comment: So it's alright to do this? Because in my understanding, by paginating query you still have to look for N records from thousands of data, per page. @DamienPirsy

Comment: By the way, did you read about [Caching queries](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#caching-queries) or [Cache](http://laravel.com/docs/cache) in general?

Comment: No, by paginating you tell Laravel to query only for *N* records at a time

Comment: I read that, but I don't know to make Cache `remember` until user logs out (those data are pulled when user logs in), and each user have different data so if using cache there will be a lot of different cache file to be processed @DamienPirsy